# Returning a list of rows that are unique by type and returning the first pass

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
ID UserID TYPE    PASS   DATE

1  12 TRACK1  1         20140101
2  32 TRACK2  0     20140105
3  43 PULL1   1     20140105
4  66 PULL2   1     20140110
5  54 PULL1   0     20140119
6  54 TRACK1  0     20140120
```

So users can take multiple attempts for 'Type', so they can take 'TRACK1' multiple times, or 'PULL2' multiple times.

I want to return the first PASS (1) for each unique 'Type' for each user.

**I want to return both pass and fail rows, but only the first instance of a pass or fail.**

How can I do this?

**sample table and output**

```
ID UserID TYPE    PASS   DATE

1  12 TRACK1  1     20140101
2  12 TRACK2  0     20140105
3  12 PULL1   1     20140105
4  12 PULL2   1     20140110
5  12 PULL1   0     20140119
6  12 TRACK1  0     20140120
7  12 TRACK1  0     20140121
8  12 PULL1   1     20140115
9  12 TRACK2  0     20140125

output:
1  12 TRACK1  1     20140101
2  12 TRACK2  0     20140105
3  12 PULL1   1     20140105
4  12 PULL2   1     20140110
```

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.*
from UserTrackStatus t1
join
(
  select userid, 
         type, 
         min(date) as min_date
    from UserTrackStatus
    group by userid, type
) t2 on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.type = t2.type and t1.date = t2.min_date
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3c70d/8)

Comment: but won't this return the other rows also?  I just want the first pass, not the other passes for the same type i.e. no duplicate passes, only a single row for any given UserID, Type, Pass.

Comment: @Katrina Sorry I wasn't clear, I want to return pass and fail, but only the first pass/fail not multiple rows.

Comment: I'm confused, how does it only return the first one?  Don't you need a having clause or something?   I'm confused...

Comment: @user1361315: Are you having a question about the query in this answer or is it clear to you?

Comment: I need a single row, not both pass row and fail row.  If passed, show that (first one), if failed, show that.  Now I am getting both rows, sorry I may have written in a bad way.

Comment: @user1361315: It is still unclear. Please add the output you expect into your question. Then it will be clear. Thanks.

Comment: @juergend I updated my question above with a sample table and output.

Comment: Your example output is still unclear. But I updated nonetheless my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it with CTE and `ROW_NUMBER` to identify which records comes first

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS (
               SELECT *
                   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY [UserID], [Type] ORDER BY [date] ASC ) AS rn
                FROM MyTable
                WHERE PASS = 1
             )
    SELECT *
        FROM cte
        WHERE rn = 1
```